# Parse simplexml into MYSQL

Tags: php, simplexml

I have an api, which I send to a database and the results are returned in an xml format, this works fine and i can output the results to the screen with no problem.  The xml feed is along list of property details.  What i am trying to do is store the results in a mysql database, using the code below.

```
  $feeds = array('http://web.demo.net/ademo_search.xml?  &upw=123456');
 foreach( $feeds as $feed ) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);

foreach($xml->channel->item as $item)
{

mysql_query("INSERT INTO property1 (id, department, branch, address1) 
VALUES (
    '', 
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->id)."', 
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->department)."', 
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->branch)."', 
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->address1)."')");       
     }
  }
```

When I run this code I don't get an errors, nor does the data get added to the database.

here is a link to the xml structure, as you will see for my test i am only trying to insert the first few items.

Comment: If this is a link `http://web.demo.net/ademo_search.xml?  &upw=123456` i dont find an xml there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what you need :)

I hope you like it

```
$feed = "test.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);

$arr = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($xml->houses->property as $item){
    $arr[$i][] = (string) $item->id;
    $arr[$i][] = (string) $item->department;
    $arr[$i][] = (string) $item->branch;
    $arr[$i][] = (string) $item->address->address1;
    $i++;
}
var_dump($arr); // now you have them in an array .. store them in db ;)
```

Answer (score 0):

first: in the feeds array, there are a few spaces, this might cause a problem parsing the url and return 404 error or something (not sure about that, but check it)

second: in the query, remove the  `''` because you have 4 columns with 5 variables passed to them

third: you might want to see MySQL error by adding  `or die(mysql_error())` after the query before the semicolon

fourth: consider replacing mysql with mysqli or PDO

Comment: Thanks I tried all of those except the last one at this moment and its still the same, i don't get any error message from the mysql

Comment: i.e. don't store in database until you see actual data output from your request .. use var_dump to check

Comment: I tried the url and it works fine, i also tried a simpler version which doesn't try to store the data and again that returned the xml information

Comment: can you supply a working example of the xml file structure?

Comment: goo.gl/nsY07k  this is the xml feed